# How can I get a reference to a newly pasted image if my sheet contains a data validation dropdown?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that looks something like this:

[image]

E6 contains a data validation cell. Adding data validation automatically add a new Shape to the sheet for the dropdown button.

The problem is as follows: I need to copy and paste a new Shape to the sheet. How can get a reference to the newly pasted Shape? I've seen suggestions that one should use Sheet.Shapes(Sheet.Shapes.Count). That doesn't work if you have a data validation dropdown, since it always has the highest index. Is there some other way?

**EDIT**: Note, I'm looking for a **general** way of finding the pasted image, irrespective of the amount of Shapes already on the sheet.

The only thing I could think of was to store all the shape names before pasting to figure out which one was added. Is there a simpler way?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set rng = sh.Range("C10:C11")
    rng.CopyPicture
    sh.Paste

    ' How do I access the newly added shape?
    ' sh.Shapes (sh.Shapes.Count) points to the data validation dropdown menu

End Sub
```